# Changing a paragraph via an <input type="image" src=> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a landing page about Formula 1 and here I'm stuck with a problem. The thing is when I click on a particular team's logo, the ellipse colour and the team picture itself change perfectly. But I also want the paragraph/information about the team on the left-hand side to change as well. And I can't figure out the JavaScript for that.

```js
function imgslider(anything) {
  document.querySelector('.formula').src = anything;
}

function changeCircleColor(color) {
  const ellipse = document.querySelector('.ellipse');
  ellipse.style.background = color;
}

var p = document.getElementById('williams_para');
var btn = document.getElementById('input type=image');
var txt = document.getElementById('williams')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Recursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<section>
  <div class="ellipse"></div>
  <header>
    <a href="#"> <img src="../PROJECT-4/img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index4-contact.html">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="textbox_ferrari">
      <h2 id="ferrari_head">Scuderia Ferrari</h2>
      <p id="ferrari_para">Scuderia Ferrari is the most successful Formula One Team, having bagged 283 wins, 16 Constructors' titles and 15 Driver Championships over the 91 years since it was first established. Created by Enzo Ferrari himself, the team is the oldest and most
        successful Formula 1 team in history. The Italian team has won the Constructors’ Championship 16 times and the Drivers’ Championship 15 times. <br>
        <br> The current 2022 drivers are Charles Leclerc (left) and Carlos Sainz (right).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textbox_ar">
      <h2 id="williams_head">Williams Racing</h2>
      <p id="williams_para">The Williams Formula 1 team was founded by racing enthusiast Frank Williams back in 1977. Frank managed to turn Williams into one of the most successful Formula 1 teams in history, winning 9 Constructors’ Titles and 7 Drivers’ Titles. When Williams
        entered Formula 1, they did so with the intention to fight their way to the top. This makes Williams one of the most decorated teams in the history of the sport. It is technically more successful than even Red Bull and Mercedes. When Nigell Mansell
        returned in 1991 the following year Williams dominated with the FW14B, which pioneered technology such as active suspension. <br>
        <br> The current 2022 drivers are Nicolas Latifi (left) and Alex Albon (right).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imgbox">
      <img src="../PROJECT-4/img/ferrari_team.png" class="formula">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="thumb">
      <input type="image" src="img/at.png" id="at_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/at_team.png');changeCircleColor('#1c2136')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/ar.png" id="ar_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/ar_team1.png');changeCircleColor('#832522')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/ferrari.png" id="ferrari_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/ferrari_team.png');changeCircleColor('#f31c1cd5')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/am.png" id="am_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/am_team.png');changeCircleColor('#06646e')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/merc.png" id="merc_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/merc_team.png');changeCircleColor('#50b8c0')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/williams.png" id="williams_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/williams_team.png');changeCircleColor('#222836')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/mcl.png" id="mcl_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/mcl_team.png');changeCircleColor('#ff9801')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/haas.png" id="haas_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/haas_team.png');changeCircleColor('#ee1d23')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/rb.png" id="rb_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/rb_team.png');changeCircleColor('#2f3c64')" />
      <input type="image" src="img/alpine.png" id="alpine.png_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/alpine_team.png');changeCircleColor('#114fa4')" />
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: that call to `getElementById` is invalid

Comment: `document.getElementById('input type=image')` is the one Daniel is referring to. `'input type=image'` isn't an ID

Comment: you're right that function is wrong. I somehow didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional function. Please see example below

`<input type="image" src="img/at.png" id="at_thumb" onclick="imgslider('../PROJECT-4/img/at_team.png');changeCircleColor('#1c2136');changeParaDisplay("textbox_ar")"/>`

Then write function in script

`function changeParaDisplay(className){document.querySelector('.className').display = "block"; }`

By default, you can have all others as `display: none`

Comment: I tried your method but unfortunately, it didn't work. I still don't know what am I doing wrong over here :(

Comment: also @ssdev you can see I have written a paragraph about Williams racing. It tried integrating your method with that element but it didn't work out.

Comment: this the javascript I applied with your method :  function changeParaDisplay(williams_para){document.querySelector('williams_thumb').display = "block"; }     and on the input type in html I added ;changeParaDisplay('williams_para')    is this correct?